# Universal macro which can have zero or one parameter

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

Is there any way to define macro which can have one or zero parameters?

I need something to be used as in this example:

```
#define MY_RETURN(ret) return ret;

void foo(){
    MY_RETURN();
}

int foo_integer(){
    MY_RETURN(1);
}
```

I am not able to find solution for this.

Comment: There are grounds for objecting to both possible duplicates.  It depends in part how rigid the '0 or 1' argument requirement is.  The solutions tend to allow '0 or more' arguments, rather than just '0 or 1'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C99 and later, it is possible to use variadic macros.

> #### C11 (n1570), § 6.10 Preprocessing directives
>
> `# define identifier lparen identifier-list , ... ) replacement-list new-line`

Your macro may look something like:

```
#define MY_RETURN(...) return __VA_ARGS__
```

---

If you need to count arguments, you may check [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/comp.std.c/d-6Mj5Lko_s) for instance.

Comment: I was thinking about the same idea, unfortunatelly, I have to program it for DOS, using old Borland compiler. Are you sure your syntax is correct? If yes, I will mark this as an answer.

Comment: @Mihalko: Well, if your compiler does not support C99, you may check the extensions he offers. This syntax is correct, except (unfortunately) in C89.

Comment: Thank you. It is definitelly usefull information for  compilers from these days :)

Comment: The `__VA_ARGS__` notation allows 2 and 3 and ... arguments equally as well as 0 or 1.  This may or may not matter.

Answer (score 0):

Define two MY_RETURN macros, one with parameter and one without! A kind of overloading, but for macros.

Comment: That is redefinition of macro.

Answer (score -1):

Based on the answer of [How to define macro function which support no input parameter and support also input parametr in the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13976935/how-to-define-macro-function-which-support-no-input-parameter-and-support-also-i)

Consider something like this:

```
#define MY_RETURN(ret) { \
  int args[] = {ret}; \
  if(sizeof(args) > 0) \
    return ret; \
}
```

Comment: Doesn't compile.